# Close webform error messages

Tags: webforms, javascript

I'm using the webform module for a contactform. But when the submission doesn't validate the user can't click away the alert box.

```
<a href="#" class="close">×</a>
```

Look's like there is no js function attached. Is there a setting in the module for closing the alert box or should you implement it yourself?

Answer (score 0):

I found a neat little module the other day called [Message Close](https://drupal.org/project/messageclose) which once installed, adds a simple close icon to every message, whether status or vaildation. It also resets all margins and padding so once a message is closed, the page looks exactly as it does on a fresh load.

In the js of the module, you can use jquery to make the message fade out, or slide out.

This would be perfect for closing webform validation messages without needing a page reload.